# Foreign key in superclass results in a clash while make migrations

Tags: django, django-models

**Django 1.10**

I just wanted to unify a common field in a general model and then inherit from it. I don't know how else I could adhere to DRY principle. But I can't make migrations. Could you give me a piece of advice here?

```
class GeneralModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="created_by")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Image(GeneralModel):
    ...

class Masterphoto(GeneralModel):
    ...
```

**Traceback**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
image.Image.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Image.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Masterphoto.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Image.created_by' or 'Masterphoto.created_by'.
image.Image.created_by: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Image.created_by' clashes with reverse query name for 'Masterphoto.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Image.created_by' or 'Masterphoto.created_by'.
masterphoto.Masterphoto.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Masterphoto.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Image.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Masterphoto.created_by' or 'Image.created_by'.
masterphoto.Masterphoto.created_by: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Masterphoto.created_by' clashes with reverse query name for 'Image.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Masterphoto.created_by' or 'Image.created_by'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with migrations.

Related names must be unique. The [model inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) explain what to do in this case; you can use `'%(app_label)s'` and `'%(class)s'` to automatically insert the relevant names into the generated value.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed.